# Trying to create a random name generator and i get a unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, io

If anyone can point out where I'm going wrong .

```
public string GenerateName(char gender)
    {
        string name;
        Random rand = new Random();


        if (gender == 'm')
        {

            string[] maleNames = File.ReadAllLines(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ModifiedMalesNamesList.txt");
            string[] lastNames = File.ReadAllLines(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ModifiedLastNamesList.txt");
            name = maleNames[rand.Next(0, maleNames.Length - 1)] + " " + lastNames[rand.Next(0, lastNames.Length - 1)];

            return name;
        }
        else
        {

        }
        return name;
    }
```

The compiler says unassigned local variable.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when the gender is not `'m'`?

Comment: sorry, its incomplete m is short for male when it's not m it generates a female name.

Comment: @Ken's comment is hinting to you as to the reason of the error message. The compiler is telling you, quite explicitly frankly, that there is a execution path through the method that results in the `name` variable not being assigned, even though you return its value. What value do you think should be returned when the `gender` variable doesn't equal `'m'`?

Comment: when I added the else path it still showed the error from before. When I set string name = string.Empty; it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to edit this:

From this:

```
string name;
```

To this:

```
string name = string.Empty;
```

You can not use string `name` unless you initialize it with values.

To explain the error in further details, you cannot just declare a string and return it without any values. Since string is a reference type, you need to initialize it as null, empty or any collection of character values.

In this case, in your if and else statement, there is no value of `name` on else statement so compiler will tell you the error since it detected that "**if condition might fail**" and it will go to else statement then after that it will return the `name` variable.

So if that's the case, what will be the value of `name` if it doesn't go to if statement? Compiler is smart enought to detect this. You can do this as well:

```
    string name;
    Random rand = new Random();
    if (gender == 'm')
    {
        string[] maleNames = File.ReadAllLines(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ModifiedMalesNamesList.txt");
        string[] lastNames = File.ReadAllLines(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ModifiedLastNamesList.txt");
        name = maleNames[rand.Next(0, maleNames.Length - 1)] + " " + lastNames[rand.Next(0, lastNames.Length - 1)];

        return name;
    }
    else
    {
        name = "";
    }
    return name;
```

On this case, you cover all grounds and you can safely return string `name` with values so it will not trigger an error.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work could you possibly explain why string.Empty was able to resolve the issue? that would be really helpful so i understand where the problem stems from so i don't repeat it

Comment: I edited my answer with further explanations. @DarkxDivinityX